# Requirements for building an E-Ticketing Portal (Cinemas, Shows etc) using ASP.net?

Tags: c#, asp.net, payment-gateway, portal

I'm part of a group of students, trying to Build a E-Ticketing Gateway for a Cinema Company. We are fairly good with the basics (we've done a few portals for schools). But none of this involved any money transactions. 
So I decided that before jumping in I should get a few pointers from the people who've actually done this before.

What should I/We know before starting to actually build.

So far we have planned to

- Use ASP.net WebForms as the Base
  platform
- MS SQL server
- Use jQuery for interactively choosing the seats.
- more importantly Integrate a payment gateway (no clue whatsoever)

Just to be clear this isn't an assignment/Homework. This is the real-deal !

Comment: You should know to make this question community wiki, as it is more prolonged and discussion based?

Answer (score 2):

Here are some function things

1. Atomic Transactions - you only want the system to book a seat if the payment has cleared.
2. Dealing with OnSite and Web Booking and what seats are avaible for both channels.
3. Seating Plan display and seating selection (assuming its not a free seat plan).
4. Membership/Authenticaion and Discounts
5. Show timetables
6. Show information
7. Coming Soon and reservations
8. Assuming chain of Cinemas (how to find the one you want)

Comment: In addition to #1 -- you don't want to take the payment if the system subsequently fails to allocate the seat (system error or concurrency issue).